# Given list of logical expressions, find all expressions which is true with inputs

Tags: indexing, expression, logical-operators

I have many logial expressions (only and, or, not) without nested:

```
(A or B or C) and (D or E) not (F or G)
(A or G) and (B or E) not (D or C)
(B) and (F) and (E)
(A) not (F)
(A or B or C) not (D or E)
not (C)
...
```

When I got A and B as input, I want to find out all expressions which is true:

```
(A or G) and (B or E) not (D or C) -> true
(A) not (F) -> true 
(A or B or C) not (D or E) -> true
not (C) -> true
```

The rest are false:

```
(A or B or C) and (D or E) not (F or G) -> false (input must include D or E)
(B) and (F) and (E) -> false (input must include F and E)
```

The naive solution I came up is looping all expressions and verify them one by one. But with the bigger inputs and bigger number of given expressions, I think verify one by one will not have a good performance.

So there is any other way to find all expressions which is true faster? Maybe create some intermediary data structure to make the finding logic faster.

Thank all of you guys.